# Prove the function is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-transformations

Please can you tell me how to prove that this function is a linear transformation.
The function $ \mathbb A :P(1) \to P(2)$ defined by the rule that $ \mathbb A f(x)=ax^2/2 +bx $ for any
$ \mathbb f $ in $ \mathbb P(1) $, with $ \mathbb f(x) =ax+b $ is a linear transformation.

Comment: Your notation is unusual and potentially confusing.

Comment: Don't use \int to denote a polynomial...!

Answer (score 0):

Note that we say that $\Lambda$ is linear **iff**
$\Lambda (\alpha_1 p_1 + \alpha_2 p_2) = \alpha_1 (\Lambda p_1) + \alpha_2 (\Lambda p_2)$ for all $p_1, p_2$ and all scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$.

Define $(\Lambda p)(x) = \int_0^x p(t) dt$ and note that 
$\Lambda (x \mapsto ax+b) = {1 \over 2} a x^2 + bx$.

Then check for linearity in the usual way,
\begin{eqnarray}
(\Lambda (\alpha_1 p_1 + \alpha_2 p_2) )(x) &=& \int_0^x (\alpha_1 p_1 + \alpha_2 p_2)(t) dt \\
&=&  \alpha_1 \int_0^x p_1(t)dt + \alpha_1 \int_0^x p_1(t)dt \\
&=& \alpha_1 (\Lambda p_1)(x) + \alpha_2 (\Lambda p_2)(x)
\end{eqnarray}
In other words,
$\Lambda (\alpha_1 p_1 + \alpha_2 p_2) = \alpha_1 (\Lambda p_1) + \alpha_2 (\Lambda p_2)$.

**Alternative**:

If you want to avoid integration, you could check that the
operators
$\Lambda_1 p = p(0)$ and $\Lambda_2 p = p(1) - p(0)$ are linear.

We see that $\Lambda_1 (x \mapsto ax+b) = b, \Lambda_2 (x \mapsto ax+b) = a$,
and so
$(\Lambda p)(x) = \Lambda_1 p + x \Lambda_2 p$. Then linearity follows
from the linearity of $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2$.